# redirect to https if user is logged in or display http otherwise using spring security plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a search controller which lists search results for users.  For anonymous users (not logged in) I want to display the page as http.

For logged in users (authenticated) I want to display the page as https.  The reason being is authenticated users will see an additional link in their search results.  The link pops up a modal dialog form that needs to send a secure form.

I'm using grails 2.2 and spring security plugin 2.0.  I haven't found anything in the spring security config files.  It looks like a page can be https or http, but not rendered either way depending on some condition.

I prefer not to do all https for performance reasons.  How could I do this, with some type of filter?

Comment: Have you profiled the performance and determined that it's a real issue?

Comment: I have not profiled the performance, I'm just trying to plan ahead.  For now I guess I could just go all https until its an issue.